# definition of a model category

Tags: model-categories

In Quillen's book ,,Homotopical Algebra" he defines a model category as a category with three types of arrows satyfying some axioms.

I have problems with understanding two of them. These axioms says among other things that fibrations are stable under base-change and cofibrations are stable under co-base change.

I would be thankfull if anyone could explain what exactly means this (co)base change and (co)base extension that also appers in the axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the *definition* of (co)base change or the intuitive meaning of the axioms?

A base change diagram is often called a [*pullback*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)). This is a commutative square
$$(\ddagger)\qquad\begin{array}{ccc} Z & \stackrel{\scriptsize s}{\to} & X \\ {\scriptsize r}\downarrow && \downarrow{\scriptsize g} \\ Y & \stackrel{\scriptsize f}{\to } & A\end{array}$$ initial among all those having $X\to A\leftarrow Y$ fixed - see the link or any category theory book for details.

A class ${\mathscr E}$ of morphisms called *stable under base change* if in any pullback $(\ddagger)$, $g\in{\mathscr E}$ implies ${\mathscr r}\in{\mathscr E}$.

Dually, a cobase change diagram is often called a [*pushout*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)), and ${\mathscr E}$ is called *stable under cobase change* if in a pushout diagram of the form $(\ddagger)$, $r\in{\mathscr E}$ implies $g\in{\mathscr E}$.

In model categories, classes of morphisms are often *defined* by their lifting properties with respect to other classes: If ${\mathscr C}$ is some class of morphisms, you can consider the class ${\mathscr C}^{\perp}$ of morphisms $g: X\to A$ having the property that in any commutative diagram $(\ddagger)$, $r\in {\mathscr C}$ implies that there exists a lift $Y\to X$ making everything commute. You can then check that ${\mathscr C}^{\perp}$ is *always* stable under base change / pullback - that's a good exercise on the universal property of the pullback. Similarly, you can define ${^{\perp}}{\mathscr C}$ as the class of morphisms $r :Z\to Y$ such that for any commutative diagram $(\ddagger)$, $g\in{\mathscr C}$ implies the existence of a lift $Y\to X$; then, ${^{\perp}}{\mathscr C}$ will always be stable under cobase change / pushout.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know what pullback and pushout are but I didn't know that this the case here. 

Sometimes the terminology of category theory makes me confused.

Comment: @pw1822 Sure, you're welcome!

Comment: I have another question. I am not pretty sure if I understand it well. I mean the notion of base extention.  What exactly it means?

Comment: @pw1822: Base change is synonymous to pull back, which is a categorical notion described e.g. in the link above

Comment: Is this the same as base extention? This the thing that I cannot understand :) I am not sure but as far as I know bin a pullback the map $r$ is base extention of $g$ along $f$ or something like that. Am I right?

Comment: @pw1822: Yes, that's synonymous